# Plugin error in Qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I just now downloaded a plugin named "XY tools"from fetch plugins option . I am a user of Qgis v 1.9.0.It shows me the following error: 
An error has occured while executing Python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\xytools.py", line 123, in xyToolClick
    if self.layerInfo.has_key(self.layer) or self.getXyColumns(self.layer):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\xytools.py", line 296, in getXyColumns
    dlg = XyToolsDialog(self.XY_COMBO_MSG, layer.dataProvider().fields(), layer.name())
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\xytools\xytoolsdialog.py", line 35, in __init__
    for field in fieldMap.values():
AttributeError: 'QgsFields' object has no attribute 'values'

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.9.0-Master Master, 1a723b4

Python path: ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-dev\\python\\plugins\\sextante', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\\sextante_taudem', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\\sextante_animove', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\\sextantelwgeomprovider', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\\sextanteexampleprovider', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins\\permaclim', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\mmqgis/forms', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\15491\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\pdokbaggeocoder/forms', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis-dev\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like that plugin hasn't been updated to the new API yet.

Comment: You should also update your QGIS version to the latest version so that the plugin install doesn't download the older plugins.

Comment: how to update new version Qgis can you suggest?

Comment: You will have to go though the code to update it to the new API, or you can email the author to see if they have already done it.

Comment: sorry sorry I am new to qgis .I am unable to find code for the plugin how to go there could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to QGIS, you better take the stable Version 1.8.0 Lisboa. The development version 1.9.0 is currently undergoing massive code changes for the upcoming 2.0 version.

This also affects the plugin handling, needing every plugin to be modified.

The stable version works as normal with all plugins designed earlier.

Comment: Well the code base is in release mode now so no more major changes however plugins are yet to be updated.